# F#: Adding items to a dictionary on a timer

Tags: dictionary, timer, f#

I am creating a program which loads an assembly file (.dll) and executes methods within the assembly file on an interval and then attempts to store the result in a dictionary. The full code for that is [here](http://pastebin.com/qfh7vTxc) (pastebin.com). My issue is that it seems that adding things to a dictionary on a timer is causing the dictionary to be unable to update. I was able to cut down the relevant code reproducing this problem to the following:

```
type SomeThing() as this =
    do
        let timer = new System.Timers.Timer()
        timer.Elapsed.Add(this.AddItem)
        timer.Interval <- 3000.0
        timer.Enabled <- true
        timer.Start()

    member this.MyDict = new System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, string>()

    member this.AddItem _ =
        this.MyDict.Add("hello", "world")
        printfn "%A" this.MyDict

let mything = new SomeThing()
```

The result, if run in an interactive session or in something like LINQPad, is an output of:

```
seq []
seq []
 .
 .
 .
```

Clearly the dictionary is not changing. I also confirmed in the Visual Studio debugger that the dictionary was not changing. It is almost as if the MyDict.Add line is being skipped. I *assume* that this has something to do with my use of a type/do statement, since using a timer and a dictionary outside of a type seems to be no issue.

Can anyone point out what I've done wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
member this.MyDict = new System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, string>()
```

This is a readonly property whose return expression is `new System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, string>()`. I.e., every time the property is read from, a new, different dictionary is returned. Here's what it would look like in C# if that helps:

```cs
Dictionary<string, string> MyDict => new Dictionary<string, string>();
```

Here's what you're after, using [automatically implemented properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/properties-%5Bfsharp%5D):

```
member val MyDict = new System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, string>() with get
```

Equivalent C#:

```cs
Dictionary<string, string> MyDict { get; } = new Dictionary<string, string>();
```

Comment: Thank you! Works like a charm. I should note that the 'this' modifier on MyDict does not work with member val. Other than that this is the answer I was looking for.

Comment: @MichaelTrittin : Thanks, apparently my mental compiler isn't fully functioning yet today. ;-]